# How to Print Stream Data in Node.js to Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

It's my app.js file fetching data from by using stream and AJAX post request made through controller file....

```
app.post('/connect', function (req, res, next){

    var u_host = req.body.data.host,
        u_port = req.body.data.port,
        u_user = req.body.data.user,
        u_password = req.body.data.password,
        u_command = req.body.data.command;

    con = new connection;
    con.connect({
        host: u_host,
        port: u_port,
        username: u_user,
        password: u_password
    });

    con.on('ready', onReady);    //'ready'  --->  is a state

    function onReady(){
        con.exec(u_command, onExec); // onExec ---> is a function df -h
    }

    function onExec(err, stream){
        if (err) throw err;

        var sshResponse = '';

        stream.setEncoding('UTF8');

        stream.on('data', function (data) {
            sshResponse += data;
        });

        stream.on('end', function() {
            res.json({data : sshResponse});
            //res.send(sshResponse);
            console.log('Output: ' + typeof sshResponse);
            console.log('Output New: ' + sshResponse);
            console.log('Stream : close');
            con.end();
        });

        stream.on('error', function(err){
        console.log(err.stack);});
    }
});


----------

//It's my controller.js file displaying output in browser console and angularjs as well but not well or properly formatted

outerApp.controller('dashboardController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $cookies) {
    $scope.current_user = $cookies.get('current_user');

    $scope.details = {
        host : '',
        port : '',
        username : '',
        password : '',
        command : ''
    };

        $scope.connect = function () {
        $http.post('/connect', {data:$scope.details})
            .then(function (response){
                console.log('Then : '+response.status);
                if(response.status === 200){
                    $scope.details = "";
                    console.log('Then Response : '+response.status);
                    //var log_data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                    var okeys = Object.keys(response.data);
                    //$scope.log_data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
                    var log_data = response.data;
                    $scope.log_data = response.data;
                    $scope.okeys = okeys;
                    console.log('Recieved Data : '+log_data[okeys]);
                    console.log('Keys : '+okeys);
                }
            }, function (response){
                $scope.details = "";
                $scope.err_msg = "Invalid Credentials";
                console.log('Error : '+response.status); 
        });
    }
});


----------
```

Now my question is how to print the streamed data to angularjs web page properly formatted ?????

---

[This is Coming Output (Actually Unformatted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2AzR.png)

---

[This is the way I want my output to Appear on my Angular Web Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc8BT.png)

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you are asking here.  What is in the stream?  the data is being set to `$scope.log_data` in your callback, so theoretically, {{log_data}} would render the data in your HTML document....

Comment: #Claies ... Thanks for your reply. I know that data is being sent in $scope.log_data but what exactly i want is to list all partitions and seprately in individual rows in html(angular). So i was seeking to get it with any index or else something. Currently Output is just printed as String .. And I want to format it like :
/dev/sda1 ---- line 1 --- partitions 1
/dev/sda2 ---- line 2 --- partitions 2

But it's print like as such in browser :
/dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 in one line only....
Hope so I'm clear to you now... :(

Comment: it's not possible to know how to format your data; you haven't shown what the data is.  if it's an array of information, then you can use `ng-repeat`.  if it's an object, then you would use the object's properties in the expressions.  for anything more specific, you'll need to update your question with the contents of `log_data`.

Comment: are you actually sending something other than a string?

Comment: #calies ... Thanks for Async Support to me .. A very Heartily Thanks and as you asked I've posted two Images as Update to my Question.
Img 1 --- is actually output is coming in unformatted way
Img2 --- is actually I want output to appear on web page

Thanks in Advanced... :)

Comment: that is definitely a purely unformatted string.  You'll have to write some logic to split that string into variables; most likely a combination of things like `String.Split()` along with Regular Expression patterns.  This actually doesn't have anything to do with Angular specifically, and I don't know the system you are working with well enough to suggest appropriate patterns.  I think there are some questions about unix logs posted here already, though.  I would probably consider asking a new question, specifically about how to parse that string using JavaScript.

Comment: try JSON.parse(response.data)

Comment: thannks #alex but it'll be unformatted and would produce result upto my desire as in img2.png i want